# Php image customization

Tags: php, image, photo

I have an image gallery displaying all photos from my file directory with php. I have defined what type of file to use etc but the main line of code is as below:

```
echo '<img src="'.$dir.'/'.$file.'" alt="'.$file.'" width="600px" />';
```

I know by changing the width=" " above I can alter how many images I have in a row but if i had a drop-down box, with options stating how many columns i want the photos displayed in and a button to refresh the page to show the columns option i have selected.

So for example: I select a drop down option "15 columns" and hit the refresh button, the page should then refresh and the images be redisplayed in columns of 15. How would i go about this?

Comment: I think you can do it by a loop on <li>. Your loop will check the value for operation.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using HTML Tables for it. Anyhow here is how you should do it.

```
$allowed_per_line = $_GET['columns'];

$counter = 0;
while($image = fetch...) {
$counter++;
echo "<img src='{$dir}/{$file}' alt='{$file}' />";
if($counter==$allowed_per_line) {
 echo '<br />';
 $counter=0;
}

}
```